# Why does my new Gravatar image not update on Stack Overflow after 24 hours?

Tags: support, gravatar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't my Gravatar image updating?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21793/why-isnt-my-gravatar-image-updating)

I changed my [Gravatar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravatar) image 24 hours ago, and it still does not appear on the Stack Overflow sites.

I check it at http://en.gravatar.com/site/check which confirms that it should have already been changed on sites which use it.

Do I need to flip a switch somewhere on my profile or something to get it to refresh from Gravatar?