# Avatar Change Bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-picture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn’t my Gravatar image updating?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21793/why-isnt-my-gravatar-image-updating)

Hello,

Today i've changed my avatar at Gravatar, then i wait some time, because normally about 3 minutes and the avatar here changes, but i waited all the day and i see that my avatar at StackOverflow, Meta StackOverflow, SuperUser and ServerFault doesn't have changed, but if i click in got flair? button all those boxes have my new avatar, but in all the site my posts are using the old one.

This avatar that you're seeing is my old one, the new one is a leaf.

Best Regards.

Comment: I can see your new one, the problem is apparently on your end.

Comment: I've marked this as by design because this is a problem with Gravatar, not SO.

Comment: exact dup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21793

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to log out of Gravatar.

Gravatar doesn't seem to invalidate it's cache until you are logged out. Either by doing so manually, or waiting for the session to expire (on their end).

---

I have actually prevented the cache from being invalidated, by continuing to visit http://gravatar.com everyday. I of course, didn't realize at the time it was preventing the site from invalidating the cache.

Comment: weird.  there's also Ctrl+F5 (in Firefox) that performs a full refresh (i.e. ignoring any cache).