# Edit profiles change image option require faster response

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force Gravatar Refresh](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37986/force-gravatar-refresh)

changing profile image take too much time.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that the images are being cached somewhere.

Try doing a hard refresh (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>) to clear your cache.