# It's been weeks since I changed my gravatar, but it did not update on SE

Tags: support, gravatar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't my Gravatar image updating?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21793/why-isnt-my-gravatar-image-updating)

It did update on other sites where I use it. I saw similar threads and tried the following suggestions:

- Log out from gravatar
- Log out from SO
- Clear browser cache

Checked from various computers, it is still the old one. How can I solve it?

Comment: Does the updated image appear on gravatar?  Is your email address specified here the same email specified by your gravatar account?

Comment: You *are* a fish who swims around. It's the reality of your life. Get used to it.

Comment: @Lix yes to both questions.

Comment: @Lix: You can just edit your first comment to add new links..

Comment: @bol - that wouldn't put across the message I'm trying to convey :)

Comment: Here is a work around till you get an answer - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/38020/172936

Comment: Yes, I get the idea, and that this will be closed as by-design due to the issue being one of Gravatar's. The problem with that reasoning is that I don't get to choose to use gravatar on stackoverflow or not, so inherently this is a neglected SO bug.

Comment: You don't get to choose the syntax highlighting plugins but a bug with that would be Google Prettify's problem... Not [so]...

Comment: Try changing your [so] email address...

Comment: I strongly disagree with that point. If I choose a buggy third party component to use in my application, I'm the one to blame. No wonder there are so many threads complaining about the same thing.

Comment: At blame for the choice **not for the bug.**  If you want to address *that*, then it'll have to be a feature-request to change the avatar provider - I don't recommend doing that...

Comment: Is it then your fault for choosing to use Stack Overflow, a site which depends on Gravatar for user profile images?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I don't get your reasoning and don't understand the hostile attitude from both of you. At the end of the day, this is something that doesn't work properly on the site and (as evidenced by the numerous similar threads) affects many people.

Comment: My first comment was a friendly joke, while my last comment was an extension of sorts of your reasoning. That said, your point is taken...

Comment: I was not meaning to be hostile.  If I came across like that I apologize.  It is a discussion that has happened over and over as you have stated (and have seen) by the kind of obnoxious number of dupe links I posted.  Clearly this "discussion" we are having **now** is totally unrelated to the actual question.  We are talking about the choice of provider and not the "bug".  If you want to continue **that** discussion I'm almost always in [the tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta).

Comment: At MSO we are never hostile. Even to fish. We are having too much fun to be hostile. All comments are jokes by default.  If you see a serious comment here, pease report it to the Jquery Office for Knowledge Eradication. ;-)

Comment: Still having this issue? See some debugging [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21793/why-isnt-my-gravatar-image-updating/139673#139673).

Comment: I changed my username and it updated after that.

Comment: Okay. Still just for future reference: Gravatar Support has just confirmed this to be an issue; see [Why isn't my Gravatar image updating?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21793/why-isnt-my-gravatar-image-updating/139803#139803)