# Why doesn't my picture show up on my user card in Safari?

Tags: discussion, browser-cache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Avatar not visible in thumbs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106651/avatar-not-visible-in-thumbs)

I guess we'll see if it happens with this post, but if I go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573798/how-to-change-the-from-address-in-django-email/7577200#7577200), my card doesn't load the small image from gravitar in Safari.  When the expanded card opens, it shows the question mark for a second and *then* loads the larger image.

But this seems to work in Firefox?

Is it just me?  I tried clearing my cache.  Does Safari have some sort of super-cache!?

EDIT: It does in fact happen on this post, and I forgot to mention that when I right click and go 'View Image in New Tab' it does successfully load the image in a new tab.

Comment: @Arjan Yeah it is.

Comment: No need to delete, dupes aid in search :)

Comment: @Arjan yeah I can delete it, but perhaps you should add a couple more tags to that other question so it's a bit more searchable.

Comment: Ok I won't delete it! : ) I did both Command-R and explicit "Empty Cache..."   I have noticed a similar infinite cache problem in Safari on sites I've been developing, but not sure if I ever tried just quitting it.

Comment: For future reference, Safari's Web Inspector [shows this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vOumN.png) for a normal page refresh, if (it thinks) it has cached a previous good version.

Comment: And as for Super Cache: ever tried to clear its HTML Local Storage? (Not related to the above issue.) As far as I know, one needs to [delete files on the file system](http://superuser.com/questions/236558/how-to-clear-all-html5-local-storage-from-safari) to achieve that...

Comment: That's horrifying.

Comment: Note sure what tags to add to that other question; if one knows it's a caching issue, then it is already kind of off-topic here...?

Comment: @Arjan Yeah it is, but you're going to keep getting it, since it seems to keep happening with these gravitars.  Maybe 'cache' or 'browser' or something.  Or a better title? I dunno.

Comment: Ah geez it's happened again, I've only been working for like half an hour.  This might be something that needs to be taken up with gravitar?

Comment: If you're on a Mac, and if it happens again in Safari, then please run the 2nd `sqlite3` command and the `file` command to figure out what happened? Thanks!

Comment: @Arjan, done and done.  It is the correct png.  I got the same result for `file ..` and I can open it in preview fine.

Comment: ...but: you already cleared your cache after posting your comment 2 hours ago? Or is it still NOT showing correctly in Safari?

Comment: I had cleared my cache, which did nothing, and then quit Safari, which worked... and then randomly stopped working.  I'll try quitting again but I bet it works.

Comment: I've removed the `grep` from the 1st command; given the `Last-Modified`, did you indeed change your avatar on Mon, 26 Sep 2011 03:26:56 GMT? And what value for `<Date>` do you get?

Comment: @Arjan lol yes, I really actually changed my gravAtar that recently.  To see if that would fix the caching/browser weirdness problem.  I'll poke at it a bit more when I get to work.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Avatar not visible in thumbs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106651/avatar-not-visible-in-thumbs/) I quit my browser and now everything works.

Not sure why clearing the cache didn't work, or why this did...

EDIT: or why I didn't think of trying it originally (have you tried turning it off and on again?)

Answer (score 1):

A bit too long for a comment, but to see *what* has been cached by Safari on a Mac, paste the following into Terminal:

```
sqlite3 ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db "
    select r.time_stamp, r.request_key, d.response_object
    from cfurl_cache_response r, cfurl_cache_blob_data d 
    where r.entry_ID = d.entry_ID
    and r.request_key like
      'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e61b2289afe9949e3a4ba903f6428cf4%'
  "
```

This will show you some hard-to-read details including the URLs for your small and large avatar, the time they were fetched and the content types of the responses. Like, partial output:

```
<key>_CFURLString</key>
<string>http://www.gravatar.com/[...]?s=32&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG</string>
...
<key>Content-Type</key>
<string>image/png</string>
<key>Date</key>
<string>Wed, 28 Sep 2011 19:22:00 GMT</string>
<key>Expires</key>
<string>Wed, 28 Sep 2011 19:27:00 GMT</string>
<key>Last-Modified</key>
<string>Mon, 26 Sep 2011 03:26:56 GMT</string>
```

Or to get your own small thumb from the cache into a file:

```
sqlite3 ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db "
    select hex(d.receiver_data)
    from cfurl_cache_response r, cfurl_cache_blob_data d 
    where r.entry_ID = d.entry_ID
    and r.request_key = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' ||
      'e61b2289afe9949e3a4ba903f6428cf4?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG'
  " | xxd -r -p > safari-cache.temp
```

Next, to see the file type:

```
file safari-cache.temp
```

The latter shows me:

```
safari-cache.temp: PNG image, 32 x 32, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
```