# Adding a picture to my profile on Stack Exchange

Tags: support, profile-page, gravatar, images

How do I go about adding a picture to my profile?

When I click `Change Picture`, it moves me to the Gravatar page, and even though I add a picture there it doesn't take effect on my profile page here.

Comment: Make sure you log out of Gravatar.

Comment: Make sure that you put the same email address , that you add the picture at , in your profile..

Answer (score 1):

See this [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21793/why-isnt-my-gravatar-image-updating) question

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when using Gravatar with WordPress.

Sometimes Gravatar takes some time to update the picture.
Sometimes the browser has cached the old image and doesn't update.

Try restarting your browser and make sure that the email configured in StackOverflow matches the one registered in the Gravatar.