# Not able to see the update Profile pic

Tags: support, gravatar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't my Gravatar image updating?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21793/why-isnt-my-gravatar-image-updating)

I had update my profile image and everyone else can see my new profile pic. But to me it still shows the old pic. Can I know why this is happening in my StackOverflow Account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> everyone else can see my new profile pic. But to me it still shows the old pic.

Seems like the image is being served from your local browser cache - do a hard refresh by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> to clear the cache & fetch the new image.

Answer (score 4):

Gravatar caches avatars very aggressively. It's completely normal for it to take many hours before you see changes to your avatar, even though they may immediately be visible to some others users (those who didn't have your old avatar cached).

This is [mentioned in Gravatar's FAQ](http://en.gravatar.com/site/faq/#answer-1-2):

> #### I changed my gravatar, but I still see my old one on sites!
>
> We cache your gravatars for periods of time, which means that your new gravatar will take effect after the old one expires from the cache. The reason we do this is to be able to serve your (and indeed everybody’s) gravatar images much more quickly and reliably.

Comment: So it will take a day for me to view my new gravatar, is it?

Comment: @surisahani: At worst, yes. You might see it sooner; I'm not sure exactly how long it's cached for.

Comment: If you want to see how it looks then add a character onto the end of the hash. http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/218fb58952964c66fa3e7ee16a817aa7~?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG (added a tilde)