# Different Gravatars being served for the same user

Tags: support, gravatar

I recently decided to change my Gravatar. Logged in to Gravatar and updated the picture.

At Gravatar the new picture appears on my profile and is served by this URL

```
http://s.gravatar.com/avatar/ae6d1062ad36df9ec2f9ec4b0ebe7b9d?s=80&r=g
```

However, at SO, and other StackExchange sites, the Gravatar is requested from a different subdomain

```
http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ae6d1062ad36df9ec2f9ec4b0ebe7b9d?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG
```

So the interesting thing is that for the same user/hash, subdomain `www` is serving the old image and `s` contains the new image.

Importantly, I did clear up my cache and this avatar change was done at least 2 weeks ago.

It's not a big deal for me but just wanted to put this out there. I wonder if this could partly explain why so many don't get to see their Gravatars updated on SO.

Comment: They look the same to me, albeit of different sizes (80x80 vs 128x128).

Comment: More importantly, I see that image on your profile: http://i.stack.imgur.com/o6qxW.jpg

Comment: I see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q32s.png) on the profile page and on the www gravatar link...

Comment: I see the same image as Martijn. Either way this is *probably* a Gravatar issue that we can't do much about.

Comment: See the answers here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21793/why-isnt-my-gravatar-image-updating - note that some have reported extremely long delays until they explicitly log out of Gravatar; worth a shot, as your *local* cache may not be the only cache twixt you and Gravatar.

Comment: Gravatar support has confirmed this to be an issue; see [Why isn't my Gravatar image updating?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21793/why-isnt-my-gravatar-image-updating/139803#139803) (cc. @Shog9)

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for the heads-up @Arjan