# I get some random profile pictures in the top right corner

Tags: bug, profile-picture

I have recently noticed (the past few weeks) that on Stack Exchange I get a random profile picture on the top right. This photo changes from time to time and it is always the upper quarter of a some random photo. This happens on the Chrome browser (though not in incognito mode) and not on [Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge). I do not experience similar issues with overflow sites, such as Stack Overflow and [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/tour). Here is the photo of the issue:

For now it is upper quarter of a face of someone random. Note that I have never added any photos to the website, so I don't have (never had) a profile picture.

[image: Profile picture is top part of a headshot]

Comment: You said that you experience the issue on "stackexchange website" but not on "overflow sites", can you clarify what you mean by overflow sites? Most websites on the network use the stackexchange domain.

Comment: @CaveJohnson I meant mathoverflow and stackoverflow. BTW I also don't get the issue on chrome incognito mode.

Comment: This is a weird issue but you could try clearing your browser cache. Using incognito doesn't use your existing cache which is why that causes the issue to go away. It could be that there was a temporary bug which caused a collision between the profile images of you and another person. While the issue was resolved, your browser may have cached the wrong image.

Comment: @CaveJohnson Although that would probably fix it, I think it would be better to check the cache to try to find which image it is and to make it easier to narrow down the root of the bug.

Comment: There was a similar issue back then in 2018, [Why does my datascience.stackexchange automatically use someone else's profile? Is this a bug?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315623/241919), and a(n ex-)CM recommended to use [Contact Us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact).

Comment: On the other hand, if you feel okay with this, you may want to copy the address of the wrong avatar images and mentioned it on the question, possibly to help investigate in case this is more of a client issue.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. I can't find the address of the wrong avatar. I use ctrl+shift+c  to bring the window that detects the elements. Move the mouse over the photo, it shows me the source link of the image. But when I go to that link it just shows my normal avatar.

Comment: Well, you chose to use Gravatar, can you please login in https://gravatar.com, and once inside go to https://gravatar.com/emails/ to see your past uploads? I'm pretty sure you'll find your random pictures there, and the bug is on Gravatar side, that doesn't clear its cache properly. Nothing SE can do about. (Except banning the use of the buggy and insecure Gravatar service, but that's another matter.)

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. [that's the OP avatar address](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2992755c87f9fb1ae37a5449c04db976?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1), it's cache issue most likely on Gravatar side, but maybe on the OP local side as well.

Comment: I see. Since the actual URL links to your own avatar, seems it's not an issue on the SE server side with other user's data getting mixed (like on my previous comment, and [another occurrence but with user reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367710/241919)). Maybe it's really an issue with a cached Gravatar just as per @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar's comment.

Comment: Also, very much related: [Different Gravatars being served for the same user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139053/different-gravatars-being-served-for-the-same-user).

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar I don't know how to login to gravatar, I use the same email as I use for this website but it says it does not exist.

Comment: hmm so try creating new account on Gravatar.com this might solve the issue; Maybe someone else used this email in the past, uploading the picture you saw, so hopefully you can force it to update on Gravatar side.