# Why is my avatar picture on askubuntu replaced by a "pattern"

Tags: support, status-bydesign, gravatar, identicon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn’t my Gravatar image updating?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21793/why-isnt-my-gravatar-image-updating)

The chat displays my picture but in my posts/answers on askubuntu and meta.askubuntu the "pattern" is diplayed.

Here is a link to my [AskUbuntu profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/117103/guntbert), showing that I have an avatar, and here is a [link to one of my posts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210991/error-when-running-sudo-getting-a-permission-denied/234161#234161), where you see the pattern.

[image: the user profile page]

[image: an answer in the same site]

Comment: I see your picture the same as it is here. Did you just change it? It may take time to propogate through the system.

Comment: You see the pattern, right? But when you look at my account you will see a photo

Comment: On this page I see something that is not what I see in your user profile page on this very site. It could be a cache issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most likely a caching issue or an issue on gravatars end; however, I am currently seeing the image as being the same.

Profile Image

[image]

Answer Image

[image]

Comment: Ok, thx for the explanation - I suppose the hats were the trigger

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is a caching problem. If you look at the image URL in your profile, you see the following:

> http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/09da3e750b75ae0895dffb9fc540c4f6?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG

[image: profile pic]

---

If you look at the URL in your posts, you see the following URL, except the s parameter is changed to something smaller:

> http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/09da3e750b75ae0895dffb9fc540c4f6?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG

[image: pattern image]

If you change the s parameter, you see the new image. This is coming from Gravatar, and this is not a Stack Exchange bug. As others mentioned, wait awhile to see if the CDN servers on Gravatar eventually update.

Comment: thank you for educating me on the question - It'll take some time to did through your edits :-)