# Showing incorrect Gravatar image

Tags: support, gravatar, profile-picture

I recently realized that everywhere on stackexchange my Gravtar user image isn't showed, nowhere except [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/116434/).

I'm aware this question exists: [Why isn't my Gravatar image updating?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21793/why-isnt-my-gravatar-image-updating) But I haven't changed neither my Gravatar picture nor my email for a long time.

The problem seems to be that a wrong hash is used in the request. The request (on any site except Area51) for my image looks like:

```
https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b6ff9d5130128e295b4cf69742c0458c?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1
```

But `b6ff9d5130128e295b4cf69742c0458c` isn't the hash of my email! `fcb8958be3b2d1c5049f96e900c29b14` would be the correct hash.

Additionally `&f=1` is appended to my request, which forces the default randomly image.

In Area51 my Gravatar Image request is:

```
http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fcb8958be3b2d1c5049f96e900c29b14?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG
```

I'm 100% sure I'm using the same email address.

Does anybody knows the reason for this strange request for my Gravatar image?

Comment: Have you tried changing your email address?

Comment: @MartijnPieters You mean I should try to change my email and then change it back again?

Comment: Exactly. If that doesn't work, another email address, then back again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I changed to another address, it showed another Gravatar (again including `f=1`) when I changed back it showed again my old one, and not my image.

Comment: How certain are you that the Area51 address isn't different? Have you tried changing that then changing it back again?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm certain my area51 address is the same, I checked that before posting thew question. Additionally if it was a different my image won't show up.

Comment: I cannot see what email address you are using on any of your accounts, so I am stepping through basic debugging tests. It might be possible for the field to contain a non-breaking zero-width joiner character, for example, in which case it'll **look** fine, but not actually be the same value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your avatar on Q&A sites set to "identicon". Switch it to "Gravatar" by hovering over your profile image on your profile, and you should be all set.

If you want to propagate this change to all your site profiles, go to the [full edit page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/1779477), change the image there, and then hit "Save and Copy Profile to All Stack Exchange Accounts".

Comment: Thanks that solved it. But I've never changed that. I even haven't known that's possible, strange...

Comment: But do you know why the request was using a wrong hash?

Comment: It's not wrong, it's salted. The point of these identicons is to divorce the hash from the user's email address since it's (now) our default image for folks.

Comment: Ahh, I understand. Good to hear that privacy is important to stack exchange.