# Gravatar Not Updating

Tags: support, gravatar

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Force Gravatar Refresh](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37986/force-gravatar-refresh)
>   [Why does my new gravatar image not update on stackoverflow after 24 hours?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8015/why-does-my-new-gravatar-image-not-update-on-stackoverflow-after-24-hours)
>   [Why isn’t my Gravatar image updating?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21793/why-isnt-my-gravatar-image-updating)

I got some flack for this earlier, so let me re-phrase. I added a gravatar a while ago now, and I can see the gravatar updated on sites other than stackoverflow, but not on stackoverflow. I looked around on meta, saw that other people had the same problem, tried their fixes, and still had the same problem.

I'm still having this problem. I read all the "duplicates" suggested by Downvoter, including all answers and comments. I tried the following:

1. I logged out of gravatar.
2. I logged out of stackoverflow.
3. I logged out of gravatar, stackoverflow and meta
4. I changed my email address. This updated my gravatar immediately, but only to a different (uglier) automatically generated image.
5. I cleared my browser cache.
6. I disabled my browser cache.
7. I used a different computer.
8. I used a different browser.
9. I used a different browser on a different computer, one that I rarely use and which had never been to stack overflow, meta, gravatar, or wordpress.

As far as I can tell, every previously asked question uses some combination of the above to update the gravatar, and it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: The hunt for duplicates begins

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37986

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21793

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8015

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8916

Comment: @Downvoter: which to choose!

Comment: @chester, and all I had to do was click the "gravatar" tag

Comment: Yeah, I did a search before to see if anyone had the same problem, and I saw those same posts. I changed my gravatar at least a month ago, and on one site it works and on the other it doesn't. This doesn't seem to fit with the other posts. Plus, I tried a lot of the things anyway, and they didn't seem to work.

Comment: Well, @James, how come none of the things mentioned in your comment are in the question itself (which still would have been closed as a duplicate, just like duplicates on SO are handled)?

Comment: @Arjan - I updated the question to list the different things I've tried that still don't seem to work.

Comment: I think it's just better to think about it as about bug even if SO developers don't get it as bug :P

Comment: Obviously this is a bug, I also have this problems and commont soultions don't help.